# Regular expression (regex) help: Need to delete everything on several lines after an IP address

Tags: regex, nsregularexpression, regular-language

I have several lines that are

192.168.86.3     0x1  0x2 3cbbaxrad  * br-lan
    192.168.86.213   0x1  0x2 3cccfargarad  * br-lan
    192.168.86.51    0x1  0x2 3cccfcvrad  * br-lan
    192.168.86.11    0x1  0x2 3cccfxxrad  * br-lan

I need to extract only the ip addresses so it's
192.168.86.3
192.168.86.213
192.168.86.51
192.168.86.11

Can anyone help? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This works for your test case:

```
\d*\.\d*\.\d*\.\d*
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a good fit. It only picks up numeric sequences up to three digits and with periods in between. The ()'s make it a selection sequence. So that you can use a replacement string like $1 to only deposit IP addresses.

```
(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})
```

Try out this link for more help: https://regex101.com/r/p3NdGL/1